# How to generate random numbers to populate a dynamic array according to the template type?

Tags: c++, templates, random, netbeans

I've been focusing on my latest programming exercise to implement templates to print out 2D arrays. I am only allowed to modify the implementation files. (i.e. main and the header files have to remain untouched) I got stuck on populating the arrays using random numbers according to the template type the object takes. Is there a viable way to utilize rand() to generate random numbers according to the type? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

```
 RowAray.h:
#ifndef ROWARAY_H
#define ROWARAY_H
template<class T>
class RowAray{
    protected:
        int size;
        T *rowData;
    public:
        RowAray(int);
        virtual ~RowAray();
        int getSize()const{return size;}
        T getData(int i)const{
            if(i>=0&&i<size)return rowData[i];
            else return 0;}
        void setData(int,T);
};


#endif /* ROWARAY_H */

Table.h:
#ifndef TABLE_H
#define TABLE_H
#include "RowAray.h"

    template<class T>
    class Table{
        protected:
            int szRow;
            int szCol;
            RowAray<T> **columns;
        public:
            Table(unsigned int,unsigned int);
            Table(const Table<T> &);
            virtual ~Table();
            int getSzRow()const {return szRow;}
            int getSzCol()const {return szCol;}
            T getData(int,int)const;
            void setData(int,int,T);
            Table<T> operator+(const Table<T> &);
    };

    #endif /* TABLE_H */

RowAray.cpp:
#include "RowAray.h"
#include <cstdlib>


template<class T> 
RowAray<T>::RowAray(int r) {
    size = r;

    rowData = new T[r];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        rowData[i] = static_cast<T>((rand() % 90 + 10));
    }
}

template<class T>
RowAray<T>::~RowAray() {
    delete []rowData;
}

template<class T>
void RowAray<T>::setData(int i, T value) {
    rowData[i] = value;
}


Table.cpp:
#include "Table.h"

template<class T>
Table<T>::Table(unsigned int r, unsigned int c) {
    szRow = r;
    szCol = c;

    columns = new RowAray<T>*[r];

    for(int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        columns[i] = new RowAray<T>(c);
    }
}

    template<class T>
    Table<T>::Table(const Table<T> &t) {
        szRow = t.getSzRow();
        szCol = t.getSzCol();

        columns = new RowAray<T>*[t.getSzRow()];

        for(int i = 0; i < t.getSzRow(); i++) {
            columns[i] = new RowAray<T>(t.getSzCol());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < t.getSzRow(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < t.getSzCol(); j++) {
                columns[i]->setData(j, t.getData(i, j));
            }
        }
    }

    template<class T>
    Table<T>::~Table() {
        for (int i = 0; i < szRow; i++) {
            delete []columns[i];
        }
        delete []columns;
    }

        template<class T>
        Table<T> Table<T>:: operator+(const Table<T> &t) {
            Table<T> tab;

            tab.szRow = t.getSzRow();
            tab.szCol = t.getSzCol();

            for(int i = 0; i < t.getSzRow(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j <t.getSzCol(); j++) {
                    tab.columns[i]->setData(j, this->getData(i,j) + t.getData(i,j));
                }
            }

            return tab;
        }

main.cpp:
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//User Libraries
#include "Table.h"

//Global Constants

//Function Prototype
template<class T>
void prntRow(RowAray<T> *,int);
template<class T>
void prntTab(const Table<T> &);

//Execution Begins Here!
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   //Initialize the random seed
   srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));

   //Declare Variables
   int rows=3,cols=4;

   //Test out the Row with integers and floats
   RowAray<int> a(3);RowAray<float> b(4);
   cout<<"Test the Integer Row "<<endl;
   prntRow(&a,3);
   cout<<"Test the Float Row "<<endl;
   prntRow(&b,4);

   //Test out the Table with a float
   Table<float> tab1(rows,cols);
   Table<float> tab2(tab1);
   Table<float> tab3=tab1+tab2;

   cout<<"Float Table 1 size is [row,col] = ["
           <<rows<<","<<cols<<"]";
   prntTab(tab1);

   cout<<"Float Table 2 size is [row,col] = ["
           <<rows<<","<<cols<<"]";
   prntTab(tab2);

   cout<<"Float Table 3 size is [row,col] = Table 1 + Table 2 ["
           <<rows<<","<<cols<<"]";
   prntTab(tab3);

   //Exit Stage Right
   return 0;
}

template<class T>
void prntRow(RowAray<T> *a,int perLine){
    cout<<fixed<<setprecision(1)<<showpoint<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<a->getSize();i++){
        cout<<a->getData(i)<<" ";
        if(i%perLine==(perLine-1))cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

template<class T>
void prntTab(const Table<T> &a){
    cout<<fixed<<setprecision(1)<<showpoint<<endl;
    for(int row=0;row<a.getSzRow();row++){
        for(int col=0;col<a.getSzCol();col++){
            cout<<setw(8)<<a.getData(row,col);
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: There is a lot of code here, you will get better answers if you can reduce it to the key details. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What are the problems you are experiencing?

Comment: See [`#include <random>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/)

Comment: You may want to think about what you want to ask some more. What does "generate random numbers according to the type" mean? The type is is supposed to affect which random numbers are generated? If it's supposed to mean something more like "generate random numbers and cast them to the type", what's supposed to happen if, for example, the type is `std::nullptr_t`?

Comment: If I'm reading things right, this question is about how to use `rand()` to accomplish something involving a templated type. How much of your code is relevant to the precise question being asked? Couldn't you trim off like 90% of that code to get a [mcve] showing just the scenario that uses `rand()`?

Comment: You would probably have issues by implementing template in cpp, see [why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file/)?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear from your question, but assuming you want to generate random values in different ways for different types, you can use specialization of a  template function:

```
template <class T>
T random_value(); // no definition

template <> 
float random_value<float>()
{
  return float(random()) / RAND_MAX; // number in [0, 1)
}

template <>
int random_value<int>()
{
  return random();
}

template <>
uint64_t random_value<uint64_t>()
{
  return (uint32_t(random()) << 32) | uint32_t(random());
}
```

And then inside `RowArray::RowArray` you would simply use:

```
rowdata[i] = random_value<T>();
```

To factor related specializations together (for example all integral types), take a look at `std::enable_if`.

A second way you might do this is in C++17 is with `if constexpr` and `std::is_same_v`. For example, inside your `RowArray::RowArray` constructor, you can do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
  if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, float>)
    row[i] = /* whatever you want for float case */
  else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)
    row[i] = /* whatever you want for int case*/
  else
    static_assert(sizeof(T) == 0, "unsupported type");
}
```

Take a look at the `type_traits` header to see how to test for all integral types etc.

Finally, take a look at C++ `random` library http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/ to avoid making common mistakes when working with random values.